# Does this question require scoping to remain on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic

A recent question on the main site asks: [Between the Bible and the Book of Mormon, which one has a more plausible alternate account of its invention?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/92431/51818).

Which of the [on-topic](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question formats for this site is met by this question?

Community-specific reasons given for closing a question include:

- General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer. See: On-topic and constructive examples.
- Questions seeking pastoral advice are off-topic here; your spiritual problems are too important to be left in the hands of random Internet people. See: Why can't I ask for personal advice?
- **Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed**. They must be edited to ask for one perspective, or to explicitly ask for an overview of all Christian positions.
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Additionally, **opinion-based** questions are off-topic.

--

Plausible modified scopes for this question could include:

- Addressing the question to those who believe the Bible but not the Book of Mormon (all answers, of course, would conclude that the Book of Mormon has a more plausible alternate account of its invention. The comments dialogue that sparked this question suggests that this is the answer that is being sought)
- Addressing the question to those who believe the Book of Mormon but not the Bible (this would yield no valid answers, as there is nobody in this category, unless we really stretch what is meant by the word *believe*)
- Addressing the question to those who believe both texts (this may yield quite a variety of answers, I don't know)
- Addressing the question to those who believe neither text (this would be an odd question to ask on a Christianity site, though there may be reason to believe some self-identified Christians fall into this group)

Are any of the above (or other possibilities) needed to scope this question, so that it is on-topic?

---

---

<sup>Note that this Meta question is not asking whether the community enjoys asserting the superiority of one faith tradition to another, or whether the community is effective at impartial evaluation when the personal beliefs of some community members are pitted against those of other community members--those questions are addressed elsewhere.</sup>

Comment: It's not a good question and should probably be closed as opinion based.